# How do I add subtitles to MX Player through Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, class, video

So I've checked the internet for answers but I'm not finding one's that are useful enough to help with this.

So my intent code to start video through the MainActivity.Java is this:

```
case R.id.button3:
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);            
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.Focus)), "video/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an External Player"));
    break;"
```

I wanted to know how I could automatically load up a subtitle through a URL so I can watch my videos with subtitles.

The external video I use is MX Player.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The help page for doing this is at https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/api.

You basically add an extra to the intent with the string "subs" and then a parcelable array of subtitle file names.